# SCRIPT loading first before loading all the page

Tags: html, text

1.what happens if i do so

2.the following example i was trying

> Blockquote`<script > </script> <html> <head> </head> <body> </body> </html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run the script that's inside the `script` tag. But it's good practice to not have it outside of the `html` tag.

Maybe "Put it above your body" was mistaken for "Put it at the top of your page"

Answer (score 1):

just include that script at the end of the code due to which your website will load faster and your script wont